# listen to message queue

Tags: c#, msmq

I am trying to create a console application that listens to a Message queue on my local computer. this is my code so far..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _queue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\testing");
        _queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { 
       typeof(string) });

        _queue.ReceiveCompleted += new 
       ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(queue_ReceiveCompleted);
        _queue.BeginReceive();

    }
  private static void queue_ReceiveCompleted(object source, 
         ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;
        Message msg = mq.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Body.ToString());
        mq.BeginReceive();
    }
```

my problem is like this.. First of all the program exits right after

```
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Body.ToString());
```

and I don't get the other messages in the queue.

So I tried without Console.WriteLine to see if all messages are read from the queue

```
private static void queue_ReceiveCompleted(object source, 
         ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;
        Message msg = mq.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
        mq.BeginReceive();
    }
```

but then the results were inconsistent some times it would read 1 message some times 4 and sometimes all.

so whats going on, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Servy I think this is not a duplicate, it's not the same question.

Comment: @Jimbot It's a duplicate, because it's the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BeginReceive` method is [asynchronous](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.beginreceive(v=vs.110).aspx), so it will not prevent the `main()` to exit.

What you can do is just add a `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of the `main()` to prevent this, until user interact.

Comment: Thank you! you saved the day